# How to replace a variable in a pptx-slide with an image with PPTX4J?

Tags: java, powerpoint, docx, docx4j

I need to replace a variable **${var}** with an image in a pptx slide. Also, this image has to be in a specific size (idk which yet). I think **inserting the image in a given position** in the slide would do the same for me, but the documentation for pptx4j (which gives an example of how to insert a picture in a slide) couldn't really help me.

Many thanks in advance! *:-)*

Answer (score 0):

It is relatively hard to program such image manipulation for PowerPoint files.
Maybe *SlideMight* would be a suitable solution for your use case:

This utiltiy lets you merge data with PowerPoint templates; both text and images, in slides and tables. The usage is in principle similar to mail merge, with some more advanced stuff.

See [www.slidemight.com](http://www.slidemight.com).

Disclaimer: I am the developer and seller of SlideMight.